# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.createDataFormat()Lorg/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFDataFormat;

Tags: java, jasper-reports, apache-poi, nosuchmethoderror

I have some troubles to export my report as *XLS*. The export as PDF works well.

So I tried to update to the latest *JasperReports* and *Apache POI* version:

- JasperReports: 5.5.0
- POI: 3.7
- iText: 2.1.7

But I receive always following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.createDataFormat()Lorg/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFDataFormat;
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.openWorkbook(JRXlsExporter.java:284)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReportToStream(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:927)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReport(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:697)
    com.phoenix.customermonitor.print.GenericDataSourceApp.xls(GenericDataSourceApp.java:290)
    com.phoenix.customermonitor.print.GenericDataSourceApp.exportToFormat(GenericDataSourceApp.java:335)
    com.phoenix.core.JasperReportHandlerAction.exportOrderMonitorOverview(JasperReportHandlerAction.java:242)
    com.phoenix.customermonitor.action.OrderMonitorMainAction.execute(OrderMonitorMainAction.java:217)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
    org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

**Export Code**

```
File sourceFile = new File(fileIn);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = (JasperPrint)JRLoader.loadObject(sourceFile);

String name = fileIn.substring(fileIn.lastIndexOf(System.getProperty("file.separator"))+1);
name = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf("."));
File destFile = new File(fileOut);

JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, destFile.toString());       
exporter.exportReport();
```

After some researches I tried several other Versions(+4) but I still receive this error. Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an old version library in your class path.

If the jasper report depends on  lib-xxx.jar, then make sure that there are no other lib-yyy.jar in your class path. You can do this by reviewing the jasper downloaded jar or pom.xm.

As I can guess there are some old versions of poi in your class path.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have read of this solution several times. So have already checked this. The only POI version I have in classpath is 3.7. JasperReport JAR is from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%205.5.0/jasperreports-5.5.0.jar/download

Comment: Check ever where, jre/lib/ext, classpath location, may be renamed jar file.

Comment: [The Apache POI FAQ on this topic](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) suggests some [code to help find](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) the POI jar you're really using